# Can the Google Chome Network debugger be configured to only display resources from the requested domain?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on reducing the number of requests generated by a webpage; the page also contains a large number of 3rd party components.  As a result the Chrome Network debugger contains a lot of requests to external domains.  I would like to be able to see a list of requests against the domain of the website I've loaded (e.g. if I load `example.com` I want to see requests such as `example.com/js/script.js` but not requests such as `thirdparty.com/client.js`).

Is there a filter, settings, or trick that would let me filter Chrome's Network debugger to only show requests against the domain of the loaded page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "smart" filter:

1. Click filter item to show filter panel

[image: 1]

2. Type "D" and confirm "Domain:" suggestion

[image]

3. Start typing domain name and select the one you like

[image]

Other filters are:

- Domain
- HasResponseHeader
- Is
- Method
- MimeType
- Scheme
- SetCookieDomain
- SetCookieName
- SetCookieValue
- StatusCode

"Is:running" could be used to see unfinished requests (and long polls).

"Scheme:http" could be used to find unsecure requests.

Comment: Ah, that's perfect, do you know of a page that covers other available filters?  I did a little looking without success.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such page yet. I'll make a request for it. BTW if you have ideas for more filters, just ask me, I'll be glad to implement them.